# The range of an operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $S$ be the diagonal operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ given by $Se_n= S(n) e_n$ with
$$S(n)=\begin{cases}
\frac1{n^2}& n>0,\\
 \frac1{|n|}& n<0,\\
0&n=0.
\end{cases}$$

> Why $S$ has not a closed range?

Comment: It's clear that the range is dense in $\ell^2$, for example it includes every sequence supported on a finite set. It's very easy to see the range is not $\ell^2$.

Comment: $S$ is injective on $\langle e_0\rangle^{\perp}$, but …

Comment: Let $Q=\{e_n;\;n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}\}$.  We have $\mathcal{R}(S)\supset \text{span}(Q)$ with $\text{span}(Q)$ is the set of all finite linear combinations of $e_n$ with $n\neq0$. Thus $\overline{\mathcal{R}(S)}\supset \overline{\text{span}(Q)}=(\mathbb{C}e_0)^\perp=\{ze_0,\;z\in \mathbb{C}\}$. But this is not the case. For example $\sum_{n>0}\frac{e_n}{n}$ is not in the image. Is this argument true? Thank you

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most elementary way is what you did in the comments, namely noting that $e_n \in \mathcal{R}(S)$ for all $n \neq 0$, but

$$\langle e_0\rangle^{\perp} = \overline{\operatorname{span} \: \{ e_n : n \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}\}} \not \subset \mathcal{R}(S)\,.$$

Another way is to note that $\ker S = \langle e_0\rangle$, and by the open mapping theorem, if $\mathcal{R}(S)$ were closed the restriction $T \colon (\ker S)^{\perp} \to \mathcal{R}(S)$ would have a bounded inverse. But the inverse is given by

$$T^{-1}(e_n) = \begin{cases} n^2 e_n &\text{if } n > 0, \\ \lvert n\rvert e_n &\text{if } n < 0. \end{cases}$$

This is not bounded.

Yet another way to phrase it is that if $\mathcal{R}(S)$ were closed, then - again by the open mapping theorem - there would be a $\delta > 0$ such that

$$S(U) \supset \{ y \in \mathcal{R}(S) : \lVert y\rVert < \delta\}\,,$$

where $U$ is the unit ball of $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$. But one easily verifies that

$$\frac{\delta}{2}e_n \notin S(U)$$

for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\lvert n\rvert > \frac{2}{\delta}$.